# How to save and pass token a through request object in Django?

Tags: django, middleware

So I'm trying to authenticate against a token-based authentication microservice.

I know this is not ideal, but just to start out with I have written this quick middleware.

middleware.py

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if request.token = None:
        pass
    else:
        username = validate_token(request.token)
        request.username = username
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    form = LoginForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            my_token = authservice_login(user,pass)
            request.token = my_token
```

My question is, once someone has logged in and a token is returned, how do I keep this token persistent between all requests?  I guess I'm a little foggy about the Django request object.  If I login and then go to other pages where other views are called, do I still have access to the request.token that I created during login?

I think what I'm ideally wanting is after a login, to pass this token to all requests via the middleware?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what effect you would like to achieve. If you are not concerned much about following the REST principles, you may use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) to store the information about user's being logged in or any other data associated with the user.

But Django has the [user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/) object and the **django.contrib.auth** module, which does a lot of authentication job for you. You normally don't need to keep the token persistent as the user object is persistent itself.

Tokens are most often used with REST APIs and are sent by the client along with every request via a secured connection.

Comment: I am bypassing Django's built in user object.

Comment: Simply put, I need a way to "keep" the token, as the token is only created and returned once by the auth service, so I need to keep and pass the token through all requests.

Comment: I don't think that bypassing Django's built in user object is a good idea, you will have to reinvent a lot of common tasks. 3d parties' auth services can be integrated with `django.contrib.auth`. Nevertheless, if you still prefer  doing it in your way, you may either use sessions to keep the token, or return the token to the client and then pass it with each request. Both of the latter two methods require specific attention to security. But this is another topic.
BTW, if you are building a microservice, I recommend to pay attention to http://www.django-rest-framework.org/.